# What does this typedef line mean?

Tags: c++, typedef

I'm working on a C++ project and one of the libraries that I'm using has the following line:

```
typedef void (*thread_startfunc_t) (void *);
```

Can someone please explain what this is doing.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It defines `thread_startfunc_t` as a synonym for the type "pointer to a function that takes a single argument, of type `void *`, and returns `void`".

Note that the `_t` suffix is actually reserved by POSIX, so I think this is bad code in that respect, but the use of a `typedef` for pointer-to-function types is always a good idea. This is a very common practice.

Comment: Why did you put [brackets] around "pointer to a"?  The typedef does declare a synonym for the pointer type; without the `*` before `thread_startfunc_t`, it would create a synonym for the function type.  Oh, and I don't believe `_t` is reserved by the C++ standard; I think it's reserved by POSIX.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Good points both. I'll adjust my answer. Thanks.

Comment: `typedef`ing pointer-to-function types is common, but `typedef`ing the function types themselves is also a valid approach.  For example: `typedef void (thread_startfunc_t) (void *); thread_startfunc_t *func = whatever;`

Answer (score 1):

It is a typedef for a function pointer. That is, a `thread_startfunc_t` variable is a function pointer to a function that has no return (`void`) and takes a `void*`. It makes it easier to write `thread_startfunc_t` in places you want a pointer to a function fitting the above description, instead of playing with awkward, confusing syntax all over the place.

IE:

```
void StartThread(thread_startfunc_t StartFunction); // Not actually a function, just an example.
```

Comment: So, if I now want to call method StartThread with argument function `foo` how do I do that?

Comment: @Nosrettap: You can write `StartThread(&foo)` (or just `StartThread(foo)`, if you prefer).